# Python ROUND_HALF_UP not working as expected

Tags: python, decimal, currency, rounding

I can't seem to understand the decimal docs to get 2.775 to round to 2.78 using the decimal class.

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 7
print(decimal.Decimal(2.775).quantize(
    decimal.Decimal('0.00'), 
    rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
))
>> 2.77 # I'm expecting 2.78
```

That SHOULD round to 2.78, but I keep getting 2.77.

EDIT:
Testing on python 3.4

Comment: Use the string `"2.775"`; your issue is that your actual float value is less than 2.775 and not in fact halfway to 2.78 at all.

Comment: Right. I should have tought of that! Wasted almost an hour on this... Please post this as the answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 17):

If you add a single line to your code thus:

```
print (decimal.Decimal(2.775))
```

then you'll see *why* it's rounding down:

```
2.774999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

The value `2.775`, as a literal is stored as a *double,* which has limited precision.

If you instead specify it as a string, the value will be preserved more accurately:

```
>>> import decimal

>>> print (decimal.Decimal(2.775))
2.774999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375

>>> print (decimal.Decimal('2.775'))
2.775
```