# Python 3.6.4 Decimal rounding bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Trying to round a float in Python 3.6 with rounding behaviour of rounding up on half (0.5). I ran into this bug.

`Decimal(0.925).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)`
gives `0.93`, correct
`Decimal(0.935).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)`
gives `0.94`, correct
`Decimal(0.945).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)`
gives `0.94`, wrong. It should be `0.95`

Scratching my head over this one, anyone encountered this before?

Comment: If you are using this command, it produced 0.95 `Decimal("0.945").quantize(Decimal("0.01"), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)`

Comment: I think this may be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599883/python-round-half-up-not-working-as-expected

Basically: `Decimal(0.945)` is actually being stored as `0.9449999999....`

Comment: Yep, when converting val to str, fixed the problem. Thanks guys, couldn't find that question before.